# Dummy audio on Huawei Matebook D 15 laptop

Tags: sound, ubuntu-drivers, huawei

I have a Huawei Matebook D 15 laptop that I use for work. I need to use Linux, so I installed Xubuntu 22.04, which is the latest release. Unfortunately, at the moment there is no audio driver, a fact that I could see by browsing several forums. In the discussion in the link it is clearly stated that the driver is not present even in the latest version of the kernel, i.e., 5.19.

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/i-installed-kernel-version-5-17-but-huawei-matebook-d15-sound-card-is-not-recognized/112719/42

I am using a USB sound card as a temporary solution, but it would be much more convenient to be able to find a way to get the integrated sound card working. Are there alternative solutions to make up for the lack of the driver?

Answer (score 1):

Solution for MateBook D15 BOD-WDI9 under Xubuntu 22.04: install linux-generic and remove all kernels except 5.15.0-76. Good luck !